# Jenkins error trying to raise on-demand linux ec2 slave

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Whenever I try to trigger a job that depends on that ec2 slave, it just stands in queue. I looked at the logs and saw this exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: Network interfaces and an instance-level security groups may not be specified on the same request
```

Whenever I click on build executor status on the left, there is a button that says "provision via ". I click on it and see the correct amazon linux image name that I entered under cloud on Jenkins' System Configuration, but when I click on that, I see that same exception as well... I just don't know how to fix this and cannot find any helpful information on this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm not exactly sure what was causing the error since I don't really know how the Jenkins plugin interfaces with the aws api. But after a good amount of trial and error, I was able to provision the On Demand worker by adding more details/parameters in Configuration, under Cloud.

Adding a subnet ID for the VPC and a IAM Instance profile did the trick (I already had everything else including security groups, availability zone, instance type, etc). So it seems like you either leave out security groups, or go all in and fill in pretty much everything.

Comment: Thanks! setting the VPC subnet worked for me (no IAM instance profile)

Answer (score 2):

As an FYI if you see this with Jenkins EC2 Plugin v1.46 it looks like a genuine bug:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-59543

The solution is to use 1.45 until it's fixed (see link above for more details).